# How to pass HashMap with respect to associated array as parameter in stored procedure using Java

Tags: java, hibernate

How to pass HashMap with respect to associated array as parameter in stored procedure using Java.

I am using Hibernate so what type will be suitable to define?

I have used this for associated array in parameter:
`new SqlParameter("I_PARAM_COLL",Types.ARRAY,"USR.PARAM_COLL_TYPE")`,

```
Error: nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation:
```

Comment: Add code or explain best your question

Comment: Can you also post the full exception?

Comment: i need to execute plsql stored procedure having IN parameter I_PARAM_COLL. I_PARAM_COLL  plsql type is table of varchar(100) index of varchar(100). so what type in SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
    .withSchemaName(schema)
    .withCatalogName(package)
    .withProcedureName(procedure)();  jdbcCall.addDeclaredParameter(new SqlParameter("I_PARAM_COLL",Types.ARRAY,"USR.PARAM_COLL_TYPE") is should use